# Xamarin Forms Xamarin.Essentials: Web Authenticator with ASP.NET Web API Social Login

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I'm using Xamarin Forms mobile app with backend api using ASP.NET Web API project. The Web API is able to login with Facebook using Ajax and Web API methods such as (`api/account/externallogins`, `api/account/registerexternal`).

From Xamarin Forms mobile app, I'm trying to use web authenticator for Facebook login. I was able to launch Facebook authentication page.

After I log in successfully, the code returns to the app, but it could not get the access token needed.

Could anyone advice on how to connect Xamarin Forms and ASP.NET Web API for social login?

Reference URLs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android

https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Samples/Samples/ViewModel/WebAuthenticatorViewModel.cs

I've added the sample backend web api using for social login. By adding Facebook credentials and launch https://localhost:port/login.html, you could able to proceed for facebook login.

https://github.com/SuMingYuan-MM/WebApiTest

```
authenticationUrl = https://api.example.com/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.example.com%2F&state=maDXXfsWrKW8wN_F6KO2tQ5ErZyky2-FiRZPQhQ1Xbs1
```

In browser, I could get the following url after successful login to Facebook.

```
https://api.example.com/#access_token={access_token}&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600&state=Jp_aHFbZE4WI0jYqeiy1B1UvW7unVGblVHBt5EZNj1o1
```

[image: WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync]

[image: Facebook Login]

[image: No Access Token]